# Jquery dropdown values from json

Tags: jquery

I want to fetch my dropdown values from json and display the values from a particular id on to a text field or a div area. Here is the code for what i am doing

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/4gtgvbt7/)** I created.

I want these values to come from a json and display the values associated with it to the text box. and when I change the dropdown option, values change in the text box. how to achieve this?? Jsfiddle with a sample work flow would be great!!

here is the sample json

```
[
    { 
        "id":1,
        "chains":"Asia",
        "sites":"site 1",
        "visitors":100

    },
    {  
        "id":2,
        "chains":"North America",
        "sites":"site 2",
        "Visitors" :200

    }
]
```

**JS**

```
$("#category").change(function () {
    var dept_number = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
});
```

so, in the dropdown, based on the id, I want Asia and North America as two options, then in the text fields, first text field should show "site 1" and second field should show "100" vice versa for the next dropdown.

Comment: Where is the json? And how will you fetch value of select dropdown from json?

Comment: JSON is the data format. Where are you getting the values from?

Comment: sure you can pass the value of json object to an element you want, but you should provide your json format to make things clearer,

Comment: how does your JSON relate to your dropdown? I dont see the `dept_number`, nor the `price` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistaken, you want to know how to pull this data from a JSON file. This is how I would structure it and retrieve from it:

**JSON**: items.json

```
[
  {
    "dept": "Item 1 second",
    "price": 10,
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "dept": "Item 2 second",
    "price": 20,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "dept": "Item 3 second",
    "price": 30,
    "value": 3
  }
]
```

**HTML/JS**:

```
<div>
     <select id="category"></select>
     <input type="text" id="dept-input"></input>
     <input type="text" id="price-input"></input>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $.get('items.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.value + '" data-price="' + v.price + '">' + v.dept + '</option>');
            });


            $("#category").change(function () {
                var dept_number = $(this).val();
                var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
                $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
                $('#price-input').val(price);
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/otd1ngvL/)**

Comment: No problem. I was  a bit unsure of what you needed, but im glad I was able to nail it.

Comment: what programming language are you using to get your `Chains` variable?is that Twig?

Comment: Depending on where `Chains` is coming from, you want to turn that into JSON. In PHP you can do that by using `json_encode()`

Comment: Im using Python and django

Comment: so what happens here is, i have the chains stored in the database, i use the dynamic code {% for Chains in Cha_Chains %}

    <option value="{{ Chains.pk }}">{{ Chains.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}..... to get the chains from the database, I take the database values into Json and display them in the front end. now, I have <option value="{{ Chains.pk }}">{{ Chains.name }}</option>, this has to be tweaked in the script  so that it works well with the options coming from Json , is this possible??

Comment: I see.. so If you have this in a database, why do you need this in JSON? perhaps there are other ways of achieving your goal

Comment: I just edited the comment, I take the database values into Json so that other tasks can be achieved.

Comment: Id say you take the `Cha_chains` array and turn it into JSON. Get rid of the other code and let JS create everything for you since you are already turning it into JSON.